# SAP- Connect to SAP from using .net connectors - proxies connect to the SAP

Tags: asp.net, .net, proxy, connector, sap-dotnet-connector

hello trying to connect using ASP.net web application to SAP.

Below error occurred.

What DLL should be included?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should install the necessary packages before using them, also I found this page [SAP Connector for Microsoft .NET 3.0](https://support.sap.com/en/product/connectors/msnet.html#section_512604546)

Answer (score -1):

[image: libs]

all dll were installed , and the related reference

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: is there any additional nuget or DLL to fix the below error in import

Answer (score -1):

is there any additional library DLL to fix the below
[image]